# How to defragment .iso to boot from it?

Tags: boot, iso

When I try to boot from an iso (Ubuntu), I get

```
Iso for emulation should be in one continuous location
```

How can I defragment the iso?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu or GRUB are you using? GRUB2 should be able to boot ISOs without defragmenting.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That was a grub4dos used in an app preloaded with boot from iso option.